# Is it possible to stop individual users from sending mail?

Tags: contacts, email

I have some users who are only able to access reports, and I would like to stop them being able to directly send mails to contacts from CiviCRM.

I found [this 10-year-old information on the old forums](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=10456.0.html) -- apparently the "view contact" permission inherently includes the ability to send mails to contacts.  That post hinted at a "patch" and that maybe the functionality would be added later...does anyone know if this is currently possible? I haven't found a permission that controls email send access.

I'm using Joomla 3.9.13 and CiviCRM 5.18.2.

Answer (score 2):

The 10 years old solution seems to be the best one, have you tried and would it be possible to remove the view all contacts permission to your users that should only use the reports?

Otherwise, it shouldn't be too complicated to alter the UI and remove the send email actions on a custom extension, but that would require some coding

Comment: Hi Xavier, thanks for the response.  I can't remove the "view all contacts" permission because if I do, that information is no longer visible in the reports and the report data is incorrect.  I'll give the 10-year-old solution a try :-)

Comment: Oh, um, one problem -- the old forum post says "apply the patch in the attached file". But there is no attached file :-( Any idea what/where the patch can be found?